# search for source code with python available for Expectation maximization (EM) algorithm?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i have a data set in CSV files .i have search about most efficient techniques for imputation and found  most researchers recommend expectation maximization or hot deck imputation , but i failed to reach implementation for them with python , and the other techniques like statistical functions and value count for categorical columns didn't give me good result .
any one have an idea about implementation for these techniques with python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expectation-Maximization or EM is a general name for algorithms that use two steps to reach their target. The expectation phase - which calculates some form of gain or error, and the maximization phase which aims to maximize the gain or minimize the error. kMeans clustering is one of them - the expectation phase calculates the center of each cluster, and the maximization phase allocates points to the closest cluster center. With imputation, you can take a look at  [this link](https://joon3216.github.io/research_materials/2019/em_imputation_python.html) which describes an EM function for python.